# How to read properties with special characters from application.yml in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

application.yml

```
mobile-type:
  mobile-codes:
    BlackBerry: BBSS
    Samsung: SAMS
    Samsung+Vodafone: SAMSVV
```

1. While reading (Samsung+Vodafone)key from application yml file , we are getting. 
   concatenated String format as 'SamsungVodafone' .
2. Morever we heve tried "Samsung'/+'Vodafone": SAMSVV but the result was same and we have tried other symbol such as '-' so its working fine .
3. For reading key and value from application yml file . we have written below code.

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mobile-type")
    @Component
    public class mobileTypeConfig {


        Map<String, String> mobileCodes;

        public Map<String, String> getMobileCodes() {
            return mobileCodes;
        }

        public void setMobileCodes(Map<String, String> mobileCodes) {
            this.mobileCodes= mobileCodes;
        }
}
```

Note :Spring Boot Version 
2.0.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use square brackets not to escape any character and encode that in double quotes

```
mobile-type:
  mobile-codes:
    BlackBerry: BBSS
    Samsung: SAMS
    "[Samsung+Vodafone]": SAMSVV
```

**Output**

```
{BlackBerry=BBSS, Samsung=SAMS, Samsung+Vodafone=SAMSVV}
```

[Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding)

> When binding to Map properties, if the key contains anything other than lowercase alpha-numeric characters or -, you need to use the bracket notation so that the original value is preserved. If the key is not surrounded by [], any characters that are not alpha-numeric or - are removed. For example, consider binding the following properties to a Map:

```
acme:
  map:
   "[/key1]": value1
   "[/key2]": value2
```

Comment: Finally after searching a lot i found this answer. great! As a sidenote: If you have a property key such as this one : tenants.tenant.info@example.com don't escape just the @-sign or the whole key. It worked for me this way: tenants.tenant.[info@example.com]

Answer (score 0):

please keep in mind that the left side is a yml key, not an arbitrary string. my suggestion or your usecase would be to have a map with both on the right side such as:

```
foo:
  - name: "Samsung+Vodafone"
    code: "SAMSVV"
  - name: "BlackBerry"
    code: "BBMS"
  - name: "Samsung"
    codes: 
     - "SAMS"
     - "SMG"
```

you will have to change your class structure slightly, but you could actually reconstruct your initial approach from that.

Comment: As per requirement , We have number of code for single product . so its structure is not useful for me.

Comment: @RohanSutar this would also possible - just make the "code" and array"

Comment: @RohanSutar even if you can get around the "+" sign (which i doubt) - the left side can never be an arbitrary string. (check the specs: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html)